# Executing JavaScript on Key Press

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing some very rudimentary javascript work and seem to hit a bump. For the life of me, I can't seem to find what should be a very basic answer on Google.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function lowerCase(){
        var input = document.send.inputText;
        input.toLowerCase();
        document.write(input);
        alert(input);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <form name="send">
            <input type='text' name="inputText" onkeypress="lowerCase()"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

My intent is that the function lowerCase is executed on entering information into the textbox and pressing enter. However, I can never seem to get the function to execute.

Comment: @iambriansreed - you mean [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about...

HTML:

```
<input type='text' name="inputText" onkeypress="lowerCase(this)">
```

JavaScript:

```
function lowerCase ( input ) {
    setTimeout( function () {
        input.value = input.value.toLowerCase();    
    }, 0 );    
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vXpj8/3/

---

```
function lowerCase ( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
        this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
        e.preventDefault();
    }        
}

document.send.inputText.onkeypress = lowerCase;
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/vXpj8/1/

Notice, how I bind the event handler with JavaScript. I do this because I want to have the `event` object available in the function.

Comment: For realtime, that works absolutely perfectly. All I'm looking for however is a box that I can type something into, press enter, and then have it show the lowercase equivalent.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Should you clear out the timeout when `keyup`? Since it will consume a numbers of memory.

Comment: @Derek What do you mean? I always want to execute the timeout function, regardless of the `keyup` event.

Answer (score 0):

There's a space between the onkeypress attribute and equals sign. Remove that; it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tried it and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/jEnxH/

```
<form name="send">
    <input type='text' name="inputText">
</form>
<script>
    document.send.inputText.onkeypress = function(event){
        if(event.keyCode != 13) return;       
        this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();
        alert(this.value.toLowerCase());
        event.preventDefault();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to work when the enter key is pressed, then you'll need to deal with the form being submitted, since pressing enter in a text input element that is a form control submits the form.

More likely you want to change the value to lower case on some other event, such as keup, e.g.

```
 <input onkeyup="this.value = this.value.toLowerCase();" ... >
```

Doing this sort of thing is a bit annoying for users though, since upper case letters are magically changed to lower case. If there is a back-end requirement for lower case letters, better to deal with it there than confuse users entering text.

Answer (score -1):

a few issues with your code
first var input is a input box not the string, toLowerCase() is a string method, you need input value

```
var input = document.send.inputText;
alert(input.value);
```

second, onkeypress is excuted before text is entered, maybe you should consider change onkeypress to onkeyup

try if this helps

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function lowerCase(){
            var input = document.send.inputText;
            input.value = input.value.toLowerCase();
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <form name="send">
        <input type='text' name="inputText" onkeyup="lowerCase()">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```